# MaterialButton app:icon attribute isn't rendering

Tags: android, material-design

I wanted to add button to my xml file.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton 
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        app:icon="@drawable/doorkey"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/x"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_input_layout1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```

As you can see i added an icon to my button. But for some reason it does not appearing in design interface. For style i tried to add `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"` according to the documentation. But i got "Render problem" that says

> "Failed to find '@attr/textAppearanceButton' in current theme."

Then i changed to `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"`. I have tried to change dependency version of material design but no luck. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app theme should inherit from one of the **MaterialComponents** themes. Check your **AndroidManifest** file to see the path to the app theme and then set a correct parent for it. You can also check the documentation [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started)

Comment: Thank you. That is really worked out. I should be more focused when i am reading documentation.